# Delete Substring from JSON file (malformed)

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed, json

I am trying to delete different values from a JSON file. It's not pretty and jq returns 1 compile error. I am searching for a solution from the command-line (awk/sed).

Here is my sample data from my json-file (similiar to docker-compose):

```
aaaa"MyPorts":{"80/tcp":{},"8080/tcp":{},"9080/tcp":{},"9090/tcp":{}},aaaa  
bbbb"PROTO 9080/tcp 9090/tcp"bbbbb
cccc"TEST PROTO 80 8080"ccccc
```

All entries can be found multiple times or also within one line.

After using the replace it should look like:

```
aaaaaaaa  
bbbbbbbbb
cccc"TEST"ccccc
```

I tried sed and (awk -F[\"]) but could not get some useful results.
How can this be done ?

Update: I made the sample clearer..

There are 3 different types:...:

```
1: Delete from "MyPorts" to }},
2. Delete "Proto to \"
3. Delete from " PROTO" till one character before \", only if left from Proto is a space
```

Update 2: How can this be done if the sample data is also in one line, like this:

```
aaaa"MyPorts":{"80/tcp":{},"8080/tcp":{},"9080/tcp":{},"9090/tcp":{}},aaaabbbb"PROTO 9080/tcp 9090/tcp"bbbbbcccc"TEST PROTO 80 8080"ccccc
```

After using the replace it should look like:

```
aaaaaaaabbbbbbbbbcccc"TEST"ccccc
```

Comment: this line `ccccPROTO 80 8080"ccccc` looks strange. How diverse could be your lines? How this line `AaaA"aaa:1"cc"aaa"bbb"{}"aaA` should be treated?

Comment: I updated the sample to make it clearer.. There are 3 different types:...: 1: Delete from "MyPorts" to }}, 2. Delete "Proto to \" . 3 Delete from " PROTO" till \", only if left from Proto is a space

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**`sed`** approach:

```
sed -E 's~("MyPorts.*\},|"PROTO[^"]+"| +PROTO[^"]+)~~' file
```

The output:

```
aaaaaaaa  
bbbbbbbbb
cccc"TEST"ccccc
```

---

Bonus approach for one-line string input:

```
$ s='aaaa"MyPorts":{"80/tcp":{},"8080/tcp":{},"9080/tcp":{},"9090/tcp":{}},aaaabbbb"PROTO 9080/tcp 9090/tcp"bbbbbcccc"TES^CPROTO 80 8080"ccccc'

$ sed -En 's~("MyPorts.+\},|"PROTO[^"]+"| +PROTO[^"]+)~~gp' <<<"$s"
aaaaaaaabbbbbbbbbcccc"TEST"ccccc
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Works like a charm !!! Great and Short Solution.. Cannot mark this a solution due less reputation, Thanks RomanPerekhrest found it.

Comment: Great job at interpreting the OP's request! @biohell can [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/353652) the answer, no minimum reputation is required.

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest: if the sample data is in one line,your call doesn't work.. Can you chnage your call to reflect this ?

Comment: @biohell, all additional cases should be described in the question (with respective input fragment)

Comment: @@RomanPerekhrest: i updated the question.

Comment: @biohell, see my update

Comment: Again, also the Bonus part works perfect. You helped me understand sed better! Thanks Roman